# query a sharepoint 2010 list from excel vba to retrieve a specific record

Tags: 2010, excel, query, vba

I have created a SharePoint 2010 list with 2 relevant columns:
- Identification Key
- Version Number

I want to be able to query this SharePoint list from Excel VBA - passing the Identification Key to the query and retrieving the Version Number.

Since this list may end up having quite a few entries, I would prefer not to create an IQY connection to retrieve the data for searching.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Excel are you using?  I have not tried it but believe you can make web service calls from Excel 2013 so should be able to access SharePoint list data through REST or SOAP calls.

Comment: You can just as easily create SOAP queries from Office 2010 applications using VBA, Excel 2013 is not a necessity.

Comment: Ah - very nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can use VBA to talk to the SharePoint SOAP Web services, using the built in SoapClient class.

The web service you want to invoke is Lists.GetListItems - details here on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems(v=office.12).aspx - This page contains all the details you need to make a request, as well as the format of the response so hopefully you'll know how to parse it (if not, google/bing about for 'parsing an XML response form a web service in VBA', pretty sure it's done quite a lot already).

If you've no idea how to build a SOAP request in VBA, here's something I write many many moons ago that adds items to a SharePoint list when things are added to an Outlook Calendar - the important bits to take away and adapt to your requirements are the SoapClient bits.

Calling SharePoint from VBA Sample Code - http://sdrv.ms/12J0M4b

Comment: Thanks for the info - I will give it a try as soon as my current project gives me some breathing room.